# How do I position an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery provides a way to get the position of an element:

```
var position = myElement.position();
```

However, this function is read only.

Is there a way to set the position of my element?

Comment: You can use the CSS function, but there isn't really a way to just position an element with x and y I think.

Comment: @Pelshoff - What about .offset(), as in my answer below?

Comment: @Javid you seem to be totally right! Cool stuff, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#element").offset({ top: XXX, left: YYY})
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would just add the appropriate css to the item:

```
// Example
myElement.css({ position: relative; top: -40, left: -40 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To position you could use the CSS method:

```
$(element).css('left', '22px');

$(element).css({
  left: '22px',
   top: '10px'
});
```

This assumes you already have `position:relative` or `position:absolute` in your stylesheet. If not, you can add it as well just like you add `left` or `top`, `right` or `bottom`. Works with `z-index` as well.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: that needs a `position:relative` in there somewhere

Comment: @Joseph I'm assuming the user has already declared that in the CSS.

Comment: gotcha.  Just keep in mind, though, that jQuery's get position method will get the position of an element even if the element is staticly positioned.  Thus, the element may not have relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery UI in addition to jQuery, you can use the `position` [utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/).

```
$(selector).position({
  of: $(parent_selector),  //position against
  my: 'right',             //element being positioned
  at: 'center',            //target element
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').css({'position':'relative','top':'10px','left':'10px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position only absolutely or relatively positioned elements by setting its top and left style properties. Use `css` method and set the `position`, `top` and `left` property of the element.

```
$("selector").css({
    position: 'absolute',//Or relative
    top: 100,
    left: 100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual decision of this problem is to use `.css()` method like:

```
$(".element").css({
    position: absolute, //or relative
    top: '50px',
    left: '50px'
});
```

Functions like `.position()` return object properties `.top` and `.left`, so you can also try the next:

```
$(".element").position().top = 50;
$(".element").position().top = 50;
```

I havn't tried the last way by my self, so I'm not sure if it works, but the first one exatly does.

Answer (score -1):

No. JQuery cannot set the offset of an element. Instead, it can set the top and left properties of it. As well as it's position CSS property.